# Forms in a listview in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I need to display a list of forms, that form only has buttons submit types, i mean, the button has by default the value that i need to send to the DB.

My view:

```
class ListMatchs(ListView):
    model = Match2x1
    template_name = 'matchs.html'
```

My template:

```
{% for match in object_list %}
<form action="." method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" id="{{match.team_b}}" value="{{match.team_b}}">{{match.team_b}} ({{match.odd_team_b}})</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

I only need send the values of that submit button by POST and save it in a model, but since listview has no post, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create additional view that handles that post and change your form action from :

```
<form action="." method="post">
```

to :`<form action="path/to/view" method="post">`